# Showing and adding mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this problem:

```
$qry_display = 'SELECT subjass,objass,bp,pr,temp,rr 
                  FROM tbl_adata 
                 WHERE sick_id = "1"';

$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_view (subjass_view) SELECT subjass from tbl_adata';
```

Is there any way to combine these two statements?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? What is your expectations?

Comment: Why do you need to combine? Please also state your reason

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `INSERT...SELECT` statement. In order to do that, you need to match the number of columns of the table you want the records to be inserted to the number of columns in your `SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_view (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
SELECT subjass, objass, bp, pr, temp, rr
FROM tbl_adata
WHERE sick_id = 1
```

**[Here's another example for that.](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/mysql-insert-select-example/)**